# Dynamics CRM Web API setting up the parentactivityid issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I need to set the **parentactivityid** for the email entity the same way CRM does it automatically when replying to an email. I am using the same pattern that works for any other lookup property like this:

```
url -> "/api/data/v8.2/emails(emailID)"
value -> "parentactivityid@odata.bind": "/emails(parentEmailID)"
```

The request ends well (204) but when I check the email it returns:

```
"_parentactivityid_value":null
```

instead of assigned GUID.

Do you know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**parentactivityid** - Unfortunately this attribute is marked `IsValidForUpdate` as false in [Developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/entities/email) (sdk).

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.attributemetadata.isvalidforupdate.aspx)

Probably you have to set the subject line, smart token & leave it to platform for tracking.